# Can we Alter a table (entity) in Symfony 2.7.3 ? using CMD or manually?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**Can we Alter a table Using Command  Prompt in Symfony 2.7.3 ?**

I have 3 Fields in an entity i.e. Product.
Now i want to add new field in existing Entity,  also i want to modify field type of declared field.

I have used

```
php app/console schema:update --force
```

I have tried manual changing in Entity `product.php`, after manually changing entity file still not working. Kindly guide me accordingly. Thanks

Comment: what does php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql tells you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are generating entity, symfony ask you to choose

configuration format for mapping information:

here you should choose **annotation** format type,

i was choosing **yml** format and after generating entities i could not update my schema with:

doctrine:schema:update --force

it was always showing me **nothing to update your database is already sync with current entity metadata**

then i generated a new entity and set **configuration format type = annotation** and after that now i can modify my entity with php (Product.php) and with **doctrine:schema:update --force** its working fine and my DB Table is ALTERING perfect.

Comment: if you used **yml**  format type, you need to open in your bundle folder **Resources/config/doctrine/product.orm.yml** file and change here you can not update direct entity file inside the Entity folder.
once you changed your orm.yml file inside doctrine directory your changes will be applied on your DB table and you will see it will **ALTER** your table

Answer (score 0):

*Altering* the entity via the command line is not possible but *creating a new one* is with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity` - but that doesn't help you. You may only alter the entity manually (that is, by editing the entity.php file).

After changing the file you must run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` for the change to affect your database. Notice that this command is slightly different than the command you tried to run. Be aware, using this command should not be used on your production server.

Comment: i have used php app/console schema:update --force in development environment, i also manually cahanged the entity.php file. after making manual change when i run the command doctrine:schema:update  --foce it reflect no change in entity.php and in table as well